# fitnesse url in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, fitnesse

I have installed fitnesse plugin in jenkins and try to run fitnesse tests followed by jenkins build.
my console output looks like below:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
hudson.plugins.fitnesse.FitnesseBuilder: {fitnesseStart=False,         fitnesseHost=localhost, fitnesseHttpTimeout=60000,   fitnesseTestTimeout=60000, fitnesseTargetIsSuite=false, fitnessePortRemote=80, fitnesseTargetPage=MyTestCase, fitnessePathToXmlResultsOut=C:\software\fitnesse-logs\fitnesse-log.xml}
C:\Users\admin\.jenkins\jobs\TEST_calculator\workspace
Connnecting to **http://localhost:80/MyTestCase?test&format=xml&includehtml**
```

I wanted to edit the connecting url :

http://localhost:80/MyTestCase?test&format=xml&includehtml

because, this url is redirecting to xml page, but fitnesse is all about html page.
it has to look something like below:

http://localhost:80/MyTestCase?test&format=html

please help me editing this url.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use the FitNesse plugin. I just use a 'normal' (e.g. Maven or Ant) build combined with a single jUnit class with the `@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)` annotation. This generates a Html report directly and I use the HTML plugin to publish that. Such a test is really simple, as can be seen [in FitNesse's own tests](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/test/fitnesse/junit/FitNesseRunnerTest.java).

To simplify the configuration of this `FitNesseRunner` and allow Jenkins to control which suite to run I created by own [subclass](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/hsac/fitnesse/junit/HsacFitNesseRunner.java). The configuration options I default are `FitNesseDir`, `OutputDir` and `FitNesseRoot` and I allow a Jenkins to override de `@Suite` using a system property.

I find this approach always works (also on other build servers), or when debugging fixtures, and removes the need for any very special plugins.

Comment: it did not help me out. I wanted to edit the response in console output. this is no way related to what my requirement is, or answer my question.

Comment: I'm sorry this does not help you. I hoped to help you run your tests from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is dead but recently I had the same problem and I solve it. The problem was that I declared variables in the Suite root page. I moved all the declarations to a SuiteSetUp page and kept it empty.